# Cannot include external C++ libraries using vcpkg Viual Studio Code

Tags: c++

I am new to making c++ projects (I just know the programming language), I am trying to make a c++ project and want to import the `sqlite3` module in c++ using vcpkg.

I have successfully installed vcpkg and installed the libraries using `vcpkg install sqlite3`.

I have also used the `vcpkg integrate install` command to make it readily available to all kinds of c++ projects.

But my VS Code is not able to locate the required header file `sqlite3.h` when I try to include it in my `main.cpp` file.

I have checked the `include-path` settings of VS code and have already added the `vcpkg` include path in it but the problem still persists.

I tried to change the compilers paths many times but the problem still exists.
My compilers include: `msys-g++`, `LLVM-clang++`, and `Microsoft-msvc`.

I tried googling a lot but couldn't find a proper solution to my issue.

I find it very difficult to import any other packages/libraries in my project due to this reason as c++ does not have properly maintained package managers like npm, pub, or pip.

Comment: Modern way of using vcpkg is to use it in manifest mode. https://vcpkg.io/en/docs/users/manifests.html